# How to make the main menu of a SharePoint modern site a dynamic site map?

Tags: office-365, navigation, site, modern-experience, modern-pages

I am creating a modern SharePoint site as a documentation site for our end users. We want to create a basic hierarchy of folders and pages, and possibly pages with child pages.

```
Sales
    Creating a Lead
    Creating a Proposal
        Adjusting Prices
Administration
    Resetting Your Password
```

These are not intended to just be Word documents or other files sitting in a file directory, they're intended to be SharePoint modern pages. My questions for building and maintaining this hierarchy are:

1. How do I create a nested pages, whether they're a child of just a folder/section or a child of another page? We don't want a flat list of pages.
2. How do I display this hierarchy in the form of a sitemap in the main menu navigation *dynamically* without having to manually construct that hierarchy and edit it every time a new page is created?

Comment: Just throwing out an idea here. Can you use this? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/customlearning/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-QFDNRZkGE

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for 1st question**:

In SharePoint Online Modern Communication Sites, you can create a main menu with **Nested links & sub-links** and display the hierarchy in the form of a sitemap like shown in below image:

[image]

In SharePoint Online you can create either **Header (without link)** or **URL** for navigation to another pages/documents in your site. So you can create folders/sections using header and actual pages links using **URL**.

For Example: You can create **Sales** as a header which will not have any link associated with it and add nested sub-links **Creating a Lead** and **Creating a Proposal** under it as shown in image you attached.

According to [Organize your SharePoint sites with megamenu navigation and new “change the look” options](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Organize-your-SharePoint-sites-with-megamenu-navigation-and-new/ba-p/328068),

> Navigation should always be planned from the perspective of the user of information – the visitors to your site. And why not present them with a beautiful, organized megamenu.
>
> **Note:** the megamenu navigation layout is only available for horizontally oriented navigation's and allows for a panel display of links up to three levels.

**Reference**:

You can follow below article for more information about how you can create/move/order/remove links and sub-links in SharePoint:

[Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca).

**Answer for 2nd Question**:

I am afraid but there is no OOTB way currently to add the newly created page under navigation (Any specific folder/section) dynamically. You have to manually add the links in navigation.

**Additional Reference**:

Planning is important while creating a navigation in SharePoint sites. You can follow below article to Plan Navigation for your modern SharePoint site:

[Planning Navigation for the modern SharePoint experience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/plan-navigation-modern-experience).